# Is it a stack frame?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I don't understand why gcc even touches %esp for this code:

```
int foo(char *);

int bar(char** a)
{
    if (!a[1]) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (foo(a[1]) == -1) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

which generates with `-O2`:

```
bar:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        movq    8(%rdi), %rdi
        movl    $1, %eax
        testq   %rdi, %rdi
        je      .L7
        subq    $8, %rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        call    foo
        cmpl    $-1, %eax
        sete    %al
        addq    $8, %rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
        movzbl  %al, %eax
.L7:
        rep ret
```

And clang does something even crazy by pushing `%rax` at the start and later poping it into `%rdx`.

Is it to allocate a stack frame ? Is this related to these `.cfi` directives ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in x64, the stack must be 16 byte aligned, and the call instruction unbalanced the stack. This particular code does nothing that cares, but the compiler cannot know that any instructions inside foo care.

In fact it's always misaligned on call and is supposed to be realigned in the prolog code; however the optimizer mangled the prolog and epilog beyond recognition.

Comment: OK, I found the reference in ftp://ftp.lip6.fr/pub/gcc/summit/2003/Porting%20gcc%20to%20the%20amd64.pdf §2.2